# Calling Javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Extending a website I didn't build. I want to be able to call the ShowWindow proc with a parameter. How would I do that? New to JQuery and Javascript.

```
default.aspx

<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery-1.2.6.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a#ShowWindow').click(function() {
        window.open("TerminalInfo.aspx?", 'Info', 'scrollbars=yes,width=510,height=536');
    })
});
```

default.aspx.cs

Building the aspx dynamically...

```
    public static string ToHtml(this Location location)
    {
        var html = new StringBuilder();

        html.Append("<td><a href='#' id='ShowWindow'>ShowLetter</a></td>");              //This works
        html.Append("<td><a href='#' id='ShowWindow(\"MyInfo.aspx\")'>Read More</a></td>"); //How can I do this? It doesn't work.

        return html.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Looks to me like you are writing code that you do not understand.  Do you play with loaded guns, as well?

Comment: @Josh Stodola: JavaScript is a little safer than a loaded gun. And everyone has to start learning somewhere.

Comment: I think Josh's point is that it looks like he started coding and asking questions before have the diligence to rtfm.  Events in JavaScript are overly documented.

Comment: @Josh Stodola @Justin Johnson. It is easy to say rtfm but I spent a good amount of time on this before I asked. If you are really new to something it's like getting dropped in a cave with a candle. What a tremendous amount of time I save my employer by asking a few pointers from experienced people who have the kindness to respond? The fool is the one who is lost and never asks for directions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public static string ToHtml(this Location location)
{
    var html = new StringBuilder();

    html.Append("<td><a href='MyInfo.aspx' id='ShowWindow'>Read More</a></td>");

    return html.ToString();
}
```

and then

```
$('a#ShowWindow').click(function(e) {
    window.open($(this).attr("href"), 'Info', 'scrollbars=yes,width=510,height=536');
    e.preventDefault();
})
```

It's a little different approach but it degrades better if JavaScript is unavailable.

**Update** (to work on several links in table)

```
$('table a').click(function(e) {
    window.open($(e.target).attr("href"), 'Info', 'scrollbars=yes,width=510,height=536');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: +1 And is the only solution that doesn't make use of the onclick attribute.  I was beginning to lose faith.

Comment: Yes, better than mine.  Mine was simply responding to the obvious error.  I guess if he is going to learn JavaScript on this project we should help him learn correctly.

Comment: the only problem i see is that you aren't returning false, so the page will change

Comment: I appreciate the "correct" help! Let me work this over today and see if I can make it sing.

Comment: Thanks all. Got that to work but one question/problem. I create the html dynamically because there is a table of links. So rather than just MyInfo.aspx I call MyInfo.aspx?LocationId=x. The first one works great but for the rest it looks like the javascript is not called and the page is not loaded in its own window.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -2):

```
var strattonn = {};
strattonn.openWindow = function(url, title) {
    window.open(url, title, 'scrollbars=yes,width=510,height=536');
    return false;
}


public static string ToHtml(this Location location)
{
    var html = new StringBuilder();
    html.Append("<td><a href='#' onclick='return strattonn.openWindow('MyInfo.aspx', 'My Info')'>Read More</a></td>");
    return html.ToString();
}
```